# Finding partial sum formula

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have the following summation which I need to find the partial sum formula for:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^n ia^i
$$

I tried the following manipulation:

$$\begin{align}
S_n & = a + 2a^2 + 3a^3 + \cdots + na^n \\
aS_ n & = a^2 + 2a^3 + 3a^4 + \cdots + na^{n+1} \\
S_n - aS_n & = a - na^{n+1} \\
S_n (1 - a) & = a - na^{n+1} \\
S_n & = \frac {a - na^{n+1}}{1 - a} = \frac {a (1 - na^{n})} {1 - a}
\end{align}$$

But [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sigma%20ia%5Ei) says this is incorrect. Could someone explain where I went wrong? Am I using the correct method for this type of problem?

Comment: Hint: $S_n - aS_n = a + a^2 + a^3 + a^4 + \ldots + a^n - na^{n+1}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$S_n-aS_n=a+a^2+a^3+\cdots+a^n-na^{n+1}$

Answer (score 1):

According to https://www.tug.org/texshowcase/cheat.pdf
$$\sum_{i=0}^n ia^i = \frac{na^{n+2}-(n+1)a^{n+1}+a}{(a-1)^2}, \quad a \neq 1$$
$$\sum_{i=0}^n ia^i = \frac{a}{(a-1)^2}, \quad |a|<1$$

Note that,
$$S_n-aS_n = a+a^2+a^3+\cdots+a^n-na^{n+1}$$
Now, the series on righthand side is a geometric series with ratio $r=a$.
$$S_n(1-a) = \frac{a(1-a^n)}{(1-a)}-na^{n+1}$$
$$S_n = \frac{a(1-a^n)}{(1-a)^2}-\frac{na^{n+1}(1-a)}{(1-a)^2}$$
$$ = \frac{a-a^{n+1}-na^{n+1}+na^{n+2}}{(1-a)^2}$$
$$ = \frac{a-(1+n)a^{n+1}+na^{n+2}}{(1-a)^2}$$

Comment: what a cool cheatsheet that is!

Answer (score 0):

Note that 
$$S_n-aS_n\not =a-na^{n+1}$$
and that 
$$S_n-aS_n=a+a^2+a^3+\cdots+a^n-na^{n+1}.$$